# Can floating-point data types be used to store exact numbers at all?

Tags: types, floating-point, double

If I directly (not getting it as a result of a calculation), explicitly assign 0.0001 to a variable of a Double type, is it guaranteed to be exactly equal to 0.0001 wherever it goes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No... because it's simply impossible to represent 0.0001 as a (finite) [binary fraction](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/) - you'll get a rounding error when the literal is compiled or interpreted.

However, integer numbers can be stored without rounding - up to the limit of precision, which is of course  lower than for an integer type of the same size. And when the limit is reached, instead of an overflow, you start to lose precision, so at some point `d == d+1`

Comment: But isn't 0.0001 stored as a pair of a significand (1) and an exponent (-4)?

Comment: @Ivan: 1 * 2^-4 == 0.0625 - it's a *binary* fraction.

Comment: Then does precision-definite equality check made like Abs(x-y)<=0.0001 make sense? If not, then what could a better way be?

Comment: @Ivan: in that case, the exact value of the constant does not matter at all. But take a look at the site I linked to; it has a page about comparison and discusses some other problems that can arise.